# Detect link attribute and callout as link for NSAttributedString in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I have a link within an attributed string that is being then set for a textview. For Accessibility purpose, I want that link to be called out as a link trait, is it currently possible for an attributed string to call out different traits within the string? If not what could be an ideal solution to do that then?

Answer (score 0):

You can look for all the "style runs" of attributes within the text view's attributed text by calling `attributes(at:longestEffectiveRange:in:)` repeatedly until you come to the style run you want. Thus you can locate the link and obtain its value.